# Display PyPlot figures and text sequentially in iJulia

Tags: matplotlib, julia, ijulia-notebook

I want to display PyPlot figures and relevant text sequentially in an iJuia notebook.

```
using PyPlot
for i=1:10
    println(i)  #Relevant text info
    fig = figure(figsize=(4,1))
    plot(1:10,rand(10));title(i)
end
```

This returns figures together, placed at a varying stage of the text output. i.e. something like:
`1 2 3 4 5 6 [fig 1] ... [fig 10] 7 8 9 10`

Alternatively I've tried using `display(fig)`:

```
using PyPlot
for i=1:10
    println(i)  #Relevant text info
    fig = figure(figsize=(4,1))
    plot(1:10,rand(10))
    title(i)

    display(fig)
end
```

But this returns `[fig 1] 1 [fig 2] 2 [fig 3] 3 [fig 4] 4 .... [fig 9] 9 [fig 10] [fig 1] ... [fig 10] 10`
(duplicating the figures all together at the end)

Is there a way to use `display(fig)` sequentially without duplication?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. Perhaps not the most robust or versatile, but it seems to keep things in order. Using `display()` to display relevant text keeps the text and figure order correct, and `close(fig)` just after `display(fig)` prevents duplicate figs from being shown.

```
using PyPlot
for i=1:10
    display(i)  #Relevant text info

    fig = figure(figsize=(4,1))
    plot(1:10,rand(10))
    title(i)

    display(fig)
    close(fig)
end
```

Result: 1 [fig 1] 2 [fig 2] ... 10 [fig 10]